# Why was I given Dragon Scale Armor?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim on my Xbox One doing the Storm Cloak quest and as soon as my nickname changed to *'Storm Blade'*, Ulfric gave me a set of Dragon Scale Armor?

I'm wondering if this is normal? It seems a bit overpowered for my level (37).

Comment: Are you on PC or console? The only reference between Ulfric and Stormblade is that it is a title he gives you, when playing the Civil War questline, if you side with the Stormcloaks. He does give you a levelled sword at the beginning of the questline, but that's it.

Comment: If you're thinking whether it is overpowered, no, it is not.  You didn't craft the set, so you can't really improve it nearly as well.  Someone who worked on getting Smithing up to 100 first will be way more powerful.

Comment: The higher the level, the better equipment you will get. Just like bounties.

Answer (score 10):

[Dragonscale Armor](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Items#Dragonscale_Armor) shows up in leveled lists when you hit 46, so any quest reward or other event (such as one of the [random encounters](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions)) that give you an award from such a list might generate a piece, although it's quite rare.

The [Stormblade title](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stormcloaks#Titles) is bestowed upon you when you complete [The Battle for Fort Snowhawk](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Battle_for_Fort_Snowhawk_(Stormcloaks)). While the reward is listed as "None" on the wiki, [discussion suggests](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:The_Battle_for_Fort_Snowhawk_(Stormcloaks)#Quest_Reward.3F) that you *will* get some form of leveled armor as a reward. It looks like [this comes from the concurrent, overarching civil war quest](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Liberation_of_Skyrim#Haafingar) (the "leveled cuirass" reward).

In other words, it looks like Ulfric awards you some random leveled loot for finishing the quest, along with the title, and you happened to get lucky enough to roll some Dragonscale.